# Check if the environment variable is set run time spring boot

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My springBoot application uses some environment variables that are set on my clients, I set them in my application.properties and everything is working as expected.
All clients use the same variables.
Now a question has arisen, there is the possibility of a particular customer having or not a certain variable set. You will only need to configure the variable on some clients.
The idea is to have only one code for everyone but if I try to upload the application with a variable in its properties that doesn't exist in the application:

```
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'config'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'configClass': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'X' in value " ${INFO}"
```

Is there any way to check if a variable is set and only if I get its contents?

Comment: Use the debug mode to see if there is any additional information

Answer (score 4):

You can simply do something like this:

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanFactoryPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.core.PriorityOrdered;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;

@Configuration
public class VerifierBean implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor, PriorityOrdered {

   @Override public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory configurableListableBeanFactory) throws BeansException {
      final Environment environment = configurableListableBeanFactory.getBean(Environment.class);

      if(environment.getProperty("property1.something") == null) {
         throw new ApplicationContextException("Missing property on context bootstrap" + " property1.something");
      }
   }

   @Override public int getOrder() {
      return Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE;
   }
}
```

And you will see something like this in console:

```
[  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Missing property on context bootstrap property1.something
```

Comment: sorry for my lack of experience but I don't know how to use this class,
how should i create an instance of this object configurableListableBeanFactory?

Comment: You can copy all of the code that I have posted, and change `property1.something` with some of your own property that you have in you application.properties file. I added `@Configuration` annotation, so this bean will be automatically registered into spring context when the application is started.

Comment: I did it but the application does not start, shows the error
'Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
19-09-2019 13:46:59.988 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication.reportFailure - Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Missing property on context bootstrap${bws.info.siteremoto}
 at com.speedsoft.bws.useful.VerifierBean.postProcessBeanFactory(VerifierBean.java:20)'
Shouldn't I invoke my startup class later?

Comment: Can you post what you have added instead of `property1.something`?

Comment: `if(environment.getProperty("${bws.info.siteremoto}") == null) {
            throw new ApplicationContextException("Missing property on context bootstrap" + " property1.something");`
        }

application.properties
`bws.info.siteremoto= ${BWS_INFO_SITE}`

Comment: Can you change if condition to this and try again:
`if(environment.getProperty("bws.info.siteremoto)== null)...`